# Splash does not render the elements created by javascript

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, scrapy-splash, python-requests-html

I know there are a couple of posts asking the same questions. I have tried them all but after a couple of sleepless nights, I had to ask the question and I will be very appreciative if someone can help me with the problem.

So I am trying to get the reviews from a yelp restaurants page using Python. The reviews are generated dynamically using javascript. I tried every possible way with scrapy, requests-html, scrapy_splash, beautifulSoup. Nothing worked. I realized that even when using Splash by itself through the browser using localhost:8050, I still get the same problem. I tried to disable the private mode and increase the wait time but that did not fix the problem. I also tried it on both firefox and chromium, still the same.

Here is the page I am testing
https://www.yelp.com/biz/brendas-french-soul-food-san-francisco-5

You will notice that the divs containing the reviews are missing.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The reviews you are searching for are loaded by js requesting this endpoint

```
https://www.yelp.com/biz/lJAGnYzku5zSaLnQ_T6_GQ/review_feed?rl=en&q=&sort_by=relevance_desc&start={offset value}
```

Which shows 10 comments and whole load of other data.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is very helpful in my situation. But how did you get the url?

Comment: Just clicked on the pagination button to load next page of comments. First request i was sending was that